# Convert a pixel displacement to angular rotation?

Tags: image-processing

I have camera at which i know the distance to it, its HFOV, and each frame has resolution axb. 
How would one convert a pixel displacement between the center of frame and the object into a propper angular movement. 
The way i would do it HFOV/a * pixel displacement.. but that just feel incorrect?

Comment: Do you mean that pixels at the center of the image have angle $0$ and the angle grows as you move out?

Comment: yes.. exactly..

Comment: What is HFOV?  Is that the width of the picture with some units of distance (say meters)?  So that each pixel's "width" could be measured in terms of HFOV/b?  (b is the number of pixels in the x direction.)

Comment: Horizontal FOV ... its in degree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you gave does not work (it assumes linear dependence on angle).  I will describe how you generate a formula that will give you the angle you're looking for.

For the moment, assume we are only working with the $x$-axis (the argument is the same for the $y$).  We have $b$ pixels in the $x$ direction.  Imagine a line drawn from the camera to the center of the image (it has length $\ell$ that will turn out not to really matter).  We can draw a right triangle whose hypotenuse goes from the camera to the edge of the image.  That angle made between the base (of length $\ell$ which is perpendicular to the image and meets at the center) and the hypotenuse is $\theta$ ($\theta=\frac{1}{2}HFOV$).  Suppose that we are interested in the pixel that is $x$ pixels away from center.  Draw a line from the camera to this point and call the angle it makes with the base $\phi$.  Angle $\phi$ is the one you are interested in finding.

Using some right-triangle trig, we have two triangles with a common base.  We have that $\tan(\theta)=\frac{b/2}{\ell}$ and $\tan(\phi)=\frac{x}{\ell}$.  Since $\ell$ is the same in both equations, we solve both for $\ell$, namely: $\ell=\frac{b/2}{\tan(\theta)}$ and $\ell=\frac{x}{\tan(\phi)}$.  Since the $\ell$ is unchanging, we have that $\frac{b/2}{\tan(\theta)}=\frac{x}{\tan(\phi)}$.  You know $b$ (width in pixels of image), $x$ (number of pixels from center), and $\theta$ (HFOV/2).  If you want to know $\phi$ you solve the equation for $\phi$:

$$\phi = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x\tan(\theta)}{b/2}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x\tan(\theta)}{b}\right).$$

Comment: Just brilliant :)

Comment: This method only work if the length is constant right .. How much would it vary if it was deviated by a meter or so??

Comment: @sds, As long as the length is the same for the center pixel and the moved-away-from-center pixel, then the formula works.  You of course replace $b$ with $a$ if you're looking for the upward angle (instead of the sideways angle).

Comment: That was perhaps confusing.  The length doesn't matter...

Comment: it made perfectly sense :)